# Java's HttpCookie class

Tags: java, cookies

HttpCookie class documentation:

> There are 3 HTTP cookie specifications:
>
> Netscape draft
> RFC 2109 - http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2109.txt
> RFC 2965 - http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2965.txt

What about RFC 6265? Is there a class similar to HttpCookie that supports this newest specification as well?

Python has a simular [Cookie class](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.cookies.html#http.cookies.Morsel) which follows RFC 2109 which is even worse. By the way, how can you support 3 cookie specifications if some of them explicitly forbid behavior of a previous one? I am referring to the comma and semi-colon separated lists.

Comment: I also know that Tomcat isn't using HttpCookie but implements it's own Cookie class.

Comment: There is an open issue related to RFC 6265: https://java.net/jira/browse/SERVLET_SPEC-37

Comment: Ok, so is there an alternative?

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/js-cookie/java-cookie

Comment: They work with HttpServletRequest and HttpServletResponse. At the moment I am not using these since I am not supporting Servlet technology. In fact I don't know why they use HttpServletRequest and HttpServletResponse since all they are using is request.getHeader() and response.setHeader(). It would be better to define a Request and Response interface requiring these two methods. This would allow me to work with my Request and Response classes as well. Maye I will contact the developer. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an open issue related to RFC 6265: https://java.net/jira/browse/SERVLET_SPEC-37

You could use https://github.com/js-cookie/java-cookie as an alternative.